# Нужна ли запятая перед словом «полезный»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения

Я извлёк уникальный опыт(,) полезный в личной жизни.

Answer (score 3):

Да, конечно же, запятая нужна.

Из справочника Розенталя ([§ 18. Обособленные определения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108)):
**Согласованные определения**

1. Обособляются (отделяются запятой, а в середине предложения выделяются с двух сторон запятыми) распространенные определения, выраженные причастием или прилагательным с зависящими от него словами (так называемые определительные обороты), стоящие после существительного или субстантивированного слова:
   *Нас окружал со всех сторон сплошной вековой **бор, равный по величине доброму княжеству*** (Куприн).

**Я извлёк уникальный опыт, полезный в личной жизни.**

[Полезный](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/220168/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) — прилагательное; определяемое слово — опыт;
опыт (какой?) *полезный в личной жизни* — распространенное согласованное определение.

> Задача курса «Философия для жизни»: трансформировать получаемые знания во внутренний опыт, полезный в повседневной жизни (Х. Ливрага, Д. Стейнберг Гусман).